# how to re-evaluate an if binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an if binding in my code, and I want to reevaluate or call that if again after clicking a button

I tried using valueHasMutated() but it did not call the run through the if again.

```
<!-- ko if: $data.Status() == "Underwriting" -->
<div data-bind="css:$data.getStatusImageClass(DealerCenter.Models.Enumerations.DealStatusColor.Red)">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: $data.Status() != "Underwriting" -->
<div data-bind="css:$data.getStatus('Underwriting')">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is my ViewModel part

```
 Status: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("") ;

        stageStr(stage: any, subStage: any) {
            statusStage = stage;
            statusSubStage = subStage;
            console.log(statusStage, statusSubStage);
            this.Status = ko.observable(statusStage);
            this.Status.valueHasMutated();

        }
```

if the the value of Status is changed I want to display the other Div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
this.Status = ko.observable(statusStage);
```

replaces the knockout observable handling the binding of the `Status` property of the model with the DOM elements. After this line, the DOM is still attached to the old observable containing the previous value. That is why the change is not reflected, even after manually triggering `valueHasMutated`. (which should not be called manually anyway and is also called on the new observable)

So instead of replacing the observable, assign the current observable with the new value:

```
this.Status(statusStage);
```